# Why is the Set-Content Command Cleaning the Package Config File and then Replacing the Content in the Package.config file?

Tags: xml, powershell, config, powershell-5.0, nuget-package-restore

I have a basic PS script written with the below code, with this script I want to replace the **'version="1.0.0"** with **version="19.3.0"** in the package.config file only for those NuGet packages which has the name Sungard in them. The below script does that for me but it also clears\remove the other content present in the file and keeps only the NuGet Packages beginning with Sungard. I tried using the Out-File command as well, result is same.

Any idea, why it is removing the other contents of the file after executing the script instead of just replacing what is asked?
How do I only replace the version for the Nuget Package beginning with the name Sungard in package.config file?

```
$PathofConfig = "$PSScriptRoot\packages.config"
$String='SunGard*'

$Output =  (Get-Content "$PathofConfig") | Select-String $String 
Write-Host $Output
$Output -replace 'version="1.0.0"','version="19.3.0"' | Set-Content $PathofConfig
```

Comment: PLEASE, do not post pics of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Output =  (Get-Content "$PathofConfig") | Select-String $String
```

The above line of code says that you only select the string matching the pattern you provide. Therefore, initially you get the content of the whole file but only save the matching part of that file to a variable.
You can use a ForEach loop to achieve what you need.

```
(Get-Content '$PathofConfig') | Foreach-Object {
      if($_ | Select-string -Pattern "$String"){$_ -replace 'version="1.0.0"', 'version="19.3.0"'}
      else {$_}
      } | Set-Content $PathofConfig
```

Answer (score 3):

`Set-Content` does *exactly what its name implies* - it sets the content of a file to whatever you pipe to it.

So when you pipe only 3 lines of text to it, that's what ends up in the file - nothing more, nothing less.

Since your target file is an XML file, I suggest using PowerShell's built-in XML parsing capabilities to modify it instead:

```
$config = [xml]::new()
$config.Load($PathofConfig)

foreach($package in $config.packages.package){
  if($package.id -like $string -and $package.version -eq '1.0.0'){
    $package.version = '19.3.0'
  }
}

$config.Save($PathofConfig)
```

---

If you insist on doing this with regex, make sure the prefix test is part of the `-replace` operation:

```
$content = Get-Content $PathofConfig

# need to translate the pattern to its regex equivalent before we can use it
$string = 'Sunguard.*'

$content -replace "(?=${string})version=`"1.0.0`"",'version="19.3.0"' |Set-Content $PathofConfig
```